# `std::launder` not returning correct data for Clang and GCC but is for MSVC

Tags: c++

Why doesn't `std::launder` return the correct value (`2`) in Clang and GCC when the object is on the stack, and not on the heap? Even using `std::launder`.
`std::launder` is required. See [[ptr.launder]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/ptr.launder#5) which says `std::launder`
is needed when replacing an object const qualified at the top level. This is because
[[basic.life]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#8) disallows replacing complete const objects without `std::launder`, only
sub-objects.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
struct X { int n; };
const X *p = new const X{1};
const X x{1};

std::construct_at(&x, X{2});        // on stack
const int c = std::launder(&x)->n;

std::construct_at(p, X{2});         // allocated with new
const int bc = std::launder(p)->n;

std::cout << c << " " << '\n';
std::cout << bc << " " << '\n';
}
```

See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/q5aeqnb8K).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::construct_at(&x, X{2});`  has undefined behavior.

It is not allowed to create a new object in storage that was previously occupied by a `const` complete object with automatic, static or thread storage duration. (see [[basic.life]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#life-10))

Other than that you are correct that `std::launder` is required in the second case for the reasons you explained: Because the object you created with `new` is `const`-qualified. If it weren't for that the old object would be [*transparently replaceable*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#life-8) with the new one.

Comment: Ah. missed that. What a weird exception. As expected everything works correctly for `struct X { const int n; };` so long as the the top object itself isn't const. And, more significantly, `launder` isn't required!

Comment: @doug As you have seen this exception allows optimization based on `const`-ness of variables. A `const int` (or more generally `constexpr` variables) initialized by a constant expression should also be usable in constant expression as a compile-time constant. Placement-new would mess with that as well.

Comment: Interestingly, the code also works in a core constant expression. But it produces different results there as well due to an escape clause that allows std library code to have unreported UB in core constant expressions.